# Ruby on rails rails-devise-roles example app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, roles

I found [this example Ruby on rails app](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-devise-roles) showcasing `devise gem` and it's use with roles.

In the readme they mention that:

> an ordinary user can’t change their role
>
> an ordinary user can see (and edit) their own user profile

However, looking at the [users controller](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-devise-roles/blob/master/app/controllers/users_controller.rb)

```rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :admin_only, :except => :show

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    unless current_user.admin?
      unless @user == current_user
        redirect_to root_path, :alert => "Access denied."
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(secure_params)
      redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User updated."
    else
      redirect_to users_path, :alert => "Unable to update user."
    end
  end


  def admin_only
    unless current_user.admin?
      redirect_to root_path, :alert => "Access denied."
    end
  end

  def secure_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:role)
  end

end
```

We can see that all actions are allowed only for admin users, except `show`, where the current signed in user is being tested if he is the `@user` we are trying to fetch/show. That makes sense for this part of the readme "an ordinary user can see their own user profile".

What I don't get is, the readme says user can also edit their own profile, but the `update` action is only allowed to be executed by admin user (and event then, the admin is able to only change user's role? `permit(:role)`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest following a more up-to-date guide on this sort of thing:
https://altalogy.com/blog/rails-6-user-accounts-with-3-types-of-roles/

The repo you linked was last updated 4 years ago. I attempted to pull down the repo and test it locally for these points you raised and I ran into way too many issues trying to do so. Look elsewhere for guidance on this.

Edit: I did take a look through the code though and I'm not entirely sure how this app does what the README says it does.